# React hooks - exported method returns as boolean

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a simple custom hook, for some toggle functionality:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

function useDialog(initialState: boolean) {
    const [isOpen, toggleDialog] = useState<boolean>(initialState);

    const open = () => {
        toggleDialog(true);
    };

    const close = () => {
        toggleDialog(false);
    };

    return [isOpen, open, close];
}

export default useDialog;
```

and I try to reuse it inside some component:

```
const SomeDialog = (props: any) => {
    const [isOpen, open, close] = useDialog(false);

    console.log('open :>> ', typeof open); // here is function type

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={open}>open</button> // ERRROR! -> Type 'false' is not assignable
        </div>
    );
};

export { SomeDialog };
```

Why error happend on onClick? `Type 'false' is not assignable` and how to properly fix it?

Comment: I'm not getting any error. Are you getting a typing error or an error when clicking the button?

Comment: donno, perhaps typescript requires type somewhere?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try typing the function instead of the value.

```
type Hook = (initialState: boolean) => [boolean, () => void, () => void];

const useDialog: Hook = initialState => {...}
```

Without it, `open` is referred with `boolean | (() => void)` type, which is not compatible with `onClick` of type `React.MouseEvent`.

[image: Edit affectionate-gauss-vmef0]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the typing to you're custom hook like so

```
function useDialog(initialState: boolean):[boolean,() => void,() => void] {
    const [isOpen, toggleDialog] = useState<boolean>(initialState);

    const open = () => {
        toggleDialog(true);
    };

    const close = () => {
        toggleDialog(false);
    };

   return [isOpen, open, close];
}
```